# What is this blue dot and circle on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens

Under the slider, there is a blue dot/circle. What is this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was current data usage from Settings > Data Usage > Show on  lockscreen.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to improve your answer? I'm hardly able to make sense of it

Comment: Sorry my mistake, sometimes it's hard to explain myself in English, specially at night.

Comment: The circle seems to move around... does anyone know what the movement means?